# Error Building Qt Creator on Windows

Tags: qt, build, qt-creator

I'm a beginner of Qt.

I want to build Qt Creator on Windows.

so I tried it following: https://wiki.qt.io/Building-Qt-Creator-from-Git

I tried this command:

> D:\Programs\qt-creator-build>qmake -r ../qt-creator-opensource-src-3.6.1/qtcreator.pro

but I got a error like this:

> Reading D:/Programs/qt-creator-opensource-src-3.6.1/src/src.pro [D:/Programs/qt-creator-build/src]
>
> Reading D:/Programs/qt-creator-opensource-src-3.6.1/src/shared/qbs/src/lib/corelib/corelib.pro [D:/
>   Programs/qt-creator-build/src/shared/qbs/src/lib/corelib]
>
> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: script

The reference says, I have to run this command in my qt5 repository:

> make module-qtscript

I don't know how to fix it on Windows.

Comment: If you are a beginner as you say, you should be building Creator, just use the pre-built binary available for download.

Comment: Clearly @ddriver meant "you should **NOT** be building Creator", but instead download a binary. And he is right. Start here: http://www.qt.io/ide/

Comment: @jbm - yeah, haven't had breakfast yet, so I am eating NOT :)

Comment: I already know that i can download binary. but i want to develop Qt creator plugins. To develop Qt creator plugins, I need to build Qt creator from source code. So I am asking this question.